# Google Cloud Platform - Resumed Virtual Machine does not work;

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Let's start out by noting I'm an absolute noob concerning Google Cloud Platform and most of it's features. My friend ask me to take a look at an issue regarding WordPress:

There Has Been a Critical Error on Your Website

I read somewhere that it would be possible to connect to SSH and deactivate the WP plugin's so I entered Google Cloud Platform and first tried "Turning the virtual machine off and on again" (Suspend and Resume). Now, instead of the critical error, the website is completely unreachable and I am at a total loss. The message read:

nickysmassage.nl has denied your connection.

I could really use some assistance in at least getting back to the original WordPress error. The domain is https://www.nickysmassage.nl.

Any suggestions on where to go from here?

Comment: 1) The default Apache page is displaying at http://www.nickysmassage.nl/ 2) The server is accepting connections on port 22. 3) Check if the IP address has changed. My guess is that you did not assign a static fixed IP address to the VM. If true, assign one and then update your DNS resource record values.

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your response. I checked the External IP of the VM with the DNS IP and this seems to match. I think that means the IP is set right, correct?